# How Do You Extract Multiple JSON Items In Python?

Tags: python, json

I've been researching this for hours now and can't figure out how to get this to work. I have a JSON data file with three categories in every item: deck, description, and name. I'm trying to draw the "name" value for every item 0 - 99 and that save that data to a text file.

[Format of json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CCxQ.png)

I cannot for the life of me figure how how I'm supposed to do it. I load in the data easily enough, and I can print out an individual value with this:

---

```
with open('gbdata1.json', 'r') as gbdata1:
    data = json.load(gbdata1)

print(data['results'][0]['name'])
```

---

I've tried passing it a list of the numbers I needed:

```
 names = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

   for item in data['results'][names]['name']:
       print(item)
```

but it says:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

So I tried creating a variable and then just incrementing the variable with a forloop and the += operator, but that didn't work either. I'm a total JSON newbie so if I'm overlooking something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got slightly off, what you need to do is iterate the `names` list and substitute your hardcoded `print(data['results'][0]['name'])` with iteration variable as:

```
names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
for n in names:
    print(data['results'][n]['name']) # You can access other attributes here
```

Also note that JSON keys are always `string`, so your `names = [1, 2, 3, 4]` won't work as it is since it has integer values, either you convert these elements to string or you can cast them to string before accessing the json in the for loop as:

```
for n in names:
    print(data['results'][str(n)]['name']) # You can access other attributes here
```

Comment: This was so helpful! Thanks so much!